# Invalid block list when trying to commit block list to Storage Account

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I came in a week ago to fix a bug for a client. As a daily task they translate a bunch of files and upload them as block blobs to our storage account. Here we fetch the block list, and append the new changes before committing. About 20 days ago, this task stopped working, and they received the "Invalid block list" error when trying to commit the block list. Looking at the block list, I noticed that the ID's changed from their usual format(they used to be b64 encoded dates, and now they are b64 encoded uuids).Their codebase regarding this task has not changed for about a year. I have tried updating the package to the latest version, and I get the same error.

As a way to check if there was something wrong on our end, I cleared the blocklist completely in dev, and it worked again(id's now have the same format for every change), sadly we cannot do this in production, as we would lose a lot of data. I know this error usually appears when multiple applications are trying to commit at the same time, but we confirmed this was not the case here.

So what could be the reason for this to happen? Have there been any changes made to Azure storage accounts lately or some other external factor? Or should the problem lie somewhere on my client's end?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I should specify that the error doesn't happen on every upload, but sometimes(seemingly random).

Comment: Hi, @Mase Can you share the code what you have tried?

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to share their code, however it is pretty much identical to @sampaths upload_blocks function. It usually works, however for one data source in particular, all we receieve now when trying to update the blob is the mentioned error. Could this be an existing issue in our blocklist itself, so when i try to update it, it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

The Commit Block List operation writes a blob by specifying the list of block IDs that make up the [blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python).

> When all of the blocks that make up a blob are staged, you can commit them to Blob Storage.
> Use the following [method](https://johnatten.com/2013/05/24/understanding-windows-azure-blob-storage-a-quick-overview/)  to create a new block to be committed as part of a [blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python):
>
> - [stage_block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-stage-block)
>
> > - Use the following method to write a blob by specifying the list of block IDs that make up the blob:
>
> - [commit_block_list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-commit-block-list)
>
> > - You create or [modify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.blockblobservice?view=azure-python-previous) a block [blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs) by writing a set of blocks and committing them by their block [IDs](https://panda-asish.medium.com/transferring-data-between-azure-storage-accounts-using-azure-blob-storage-client-library-6d0feb81f8be)

- Code reference is taken from [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python)

```py
import os
import uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobBlock

class YourUploaderClass:
    def upload_blocks(self, blob_container_client, local_file_path, block_size):
        try:
            file_name = os.path.basename(local_file_path)
            blob_client = blob_container_client.get_blob_client(file_name)

            with open(file=local_file_path, mode="rb") as file_stream:
                block_id_list = []

                while True:
                    buffer = file_stream.read(block_size)
                    if not buffer:
                        break

                    block_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
                    block_id_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id=block_id))

                    blob_client.stage_block(block_id=block_id, data=buffer, length=len(buffer))

                blob_client.commit_block_list(block_id_list)

            print(f"File '{file_name}' uploaded successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error uploading file: {str(e)}")

# Example usage
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Replace <your_connection_string> with your actual connection string
    connection_string = "AzureStorageConnectionString"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    # Replace "your_container_name" with the actual container name
    container_name = "AzureStoragContainerName"

    # Replace "your_local_file_path" with the actual local file path
    local_file_path = "C:/Users/Sequential.html"

    # Replace 40 * 1024 * 1024 with your desired block size
    block_size = 40 * 1024 * 1024

    # Create an instance of the class containing the upload_blocks method
    uploader = YourUploaderClass()

    # Get the container client
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

    # Call the upload_blocks method
    uploader.upload_blocks(container_client, local_file_path, block_size)
```

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

Comment: I have implemented it just like your example, and the error persists. Note that this error doesn't happen with all the imported files, just some.